# Reindex data on magento via SSH

Tags: magento

I've tried to reindex data via ssh on magento , So I logged into SSH and typed this command :

```
php -f indexer.php reindexall
```

I also tried this one :

```
php indexer.php reindexall
```

But nothing happend . It returns this :

```
    Usage:  php -f indexer.php -- [options]

  --status <indexer>            Show Indexer(s) Status
  --mode <indexer>              Show Indexer(s) Index Mode
  --mode-realtime <indexer>     Set index mode type "Update on Save"
  --mode-manual <indexer>       Set index mode type "Manual Update"
  --reindex <indexer>           Reindex Data
  info                          Show allowed indexers
  reindexall                    Reindex Data by all indexers
  help                          This help

  <indexer>     Comma separated indexer codes or value "all" for all indexers
```

P.S : I've also tried this :

```
php -f indexer.php -- reindexall
```

but it's still returning the same thing as shown above .

Comment: did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

the answer is in your question, ie:

```
Usage:  php -f indexer.php -- [options]

  --status <indexer>            Show Indexer(s) Status
  --mode <indexer>              Show Indexer(s) Index Mode
  --mode-realtime <indexer>     Set index mode type "Update on Save"
  --mode-manual <indexer>       Set index mode type "Manual Update"
  --reindex <indexer>           Reindex Data
  info                          Show allowed indexers
  reindexall                    Reindex Data by all indexers
  help                          This help

  <indexer>     Comma separated indexer codes or value "all" for all indexers
```

So to reindex all indexes, you have two choices:

```
php -f shell/indexer.php -- reindexall
```

or

```
php -f shell/indexer.php -- --reindex all
```

**important**: you have to execute this command from your Magento's root directory

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: @TasawerKhan strange, I use it every day and it always work. Are you on MAGENTO_ROOT when you execute it? does it give any error message? you should give some info: saying "it doesn't work" does not allow me to help you. Thanks for the downvote anyway

Comment: yes. It is very strange considering the usage help is suggesting same. It shows this usage info http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80108/reindex-not-working-through-ssh/80113?noredirect=1#comment104972_80113

Comment: can this be character encoding issue?